# Sign API Gateway Request With AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, aws-api-gateway

When you download an auto-generated API client for Java or JavaScript they reference base helper components. Is a version of these available for Xamarin, or is there any way to make or sign requests to the API Gateway using the Xamarin AWS SDK? The only thing I see is the 'test' method in the AWSSDK.APIGateway client, which seems intended for management operations.

My API requires authentication, I'm using Cognito to authenticate users.

UPDATE:

So I didn't realize at first that it was possible to call my Lambda functions directly using the AWS SDK and I don't need to use the API Gateway at all.

Comment: How have you managed to call Lambda functions directly with AWS SDK?

Comment: There's an SDK package for it, I added the package to my project and call the invoke method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the auto-generated API clients are only available for iOS, Android, and JavaScript at this time. We have received requests for multiple other languages, which are on our backlog.

The API Gateway client in all of the traditional AWS SDKs is only built for the API Gateway control APIs, which are used to configure and deploy your RestApis.

You'll have to write/extend your own signer. This may be helpful: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-xamarin/blob/master/AWS.XamarinSDK/AWSSDK_Core/Amazon.Runtime/Pipeline/Handlers/Signer.cs

or the public signature docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

Comment: Isn't the main usage of the AWS SDKs a 'customer' user? What's the point of implementing control APIs first then the usage APIs?

Comment: The Auto generated SDK's are now available for Java it appears.